# PyQt5: change the focus border color of a QLineEdit

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5, focus, qlineedit

[image]

The selected area changes the color of the border, as shown in the image above.
Is there a way to change the color that changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use qss to change to color of border.

```css
QLineEdit {
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
}

QLineEdit:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 153, 188);
}
```

Comment: That won't change the color of the ***focus-border***.